# R: How to make extra rows from a column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data-set of human hands, where currently a single person is defined as a single observation. I want to reshape dataframe to have hands as individual observations. I tried something with "dplyr" package and "gather" function but had no success at all.

So from this, where each person is on one row :

```
id Gender Age   Present_R    Present_L    Dominant
1    F     2      TRUE         TRUE          R
2    F     5      TRUE         FALSE         L
3    M     8      FALSE        FALSE         R
```

to this, where each hand is on one row:

```
id Gender Age   Hand    Present  Dominant
1    F     2     R       TRUE     TRUE
2    F     2     L       TRUE     FALSE
3    F     5     R       TRUE     FALSE
4    F     5     L       FALSE    TRUE
5    M     8     R       FALSE    TRUE
6    M     8     L       FALSE    FALSE
```

Note that hand dominance becomes logical.

Comment: What's the logic behind Dominance?

Comment: "Dominance" means hand dominance. Each person has a dominant hand and if hands are separated then each hand will be dominant (TRUE) or nondominant (FALSE).

Comment: and for old times sake: `r = reshape(dat, direction="long", varying=c("Present_R", "Present_L"), sep="_", timevar="hand")`, then set Dominant to how you want `r$Dominant <- r$Dominant == r$hand`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can `gather` into 'long' format, `arrange` by 'id', then create the 'Dominant' by `unlist`ing the 'Present' columns, 'Hand' by removing the substring of the 'Hand' column

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, Hand, Present, Present_R:Present_L) %>%
   arrange(id) %>%
   mutate(Dominant = unlist(df1[c("Present_L", "Present_R")]),
          id = row_number(),
          Hand = str_remove(Hand, ".*_"))
#   id Gender Age Dominant Hand Present
#1  1      F   2     TRUE    R    TRUE
#2  2      F   2    FALSE    L    TRUE
#3  3      F   5    FALSE    R    TRUE
#4  4      F   5     TRUE    L   FALSE
#5  5      M   8     TRUE    R   FALSE
#6  6      M   8    FALSE    L   FALSE
```

Based on the OP' comments, it seems like we need to compare the 'Dominant' with the 'Hand'

```
gather(df1, Hand, Present, Present_R:Present_L) %>%
    arrange(id) %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number(),
           Hand = str_remove(Hand, ".*_"),
           Dominant = Dominant == Hand)
#   id Gender Age Dominant Hand Present
#1  1      F   2     TRUE    R    TRUE
#2  2      F   2    FALSE    L    TRUE
#3  3      F   5    FALSE    R    TRUE
#4  4      F   5     TRUE    L   FALSE
#5  5      M   8     TRUE    R   FALSE
#6  6      M   8    FALSE    L   FALSE
```

Comment: mutate function looks amazing!

Comment: Nice. What's the logic that led you to unlist?

Comment: Should row_number() function have an argument? For me it produces error: Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: @NelsonGon Thanks.  For me, I was initially checking the expected output.  But now, by looking at the comments the OP made, I think it is more correct to have `gather(df1, Hand, Present, Present_R:Present_L) %>%arrange(id) %>% mutate(id = row_number(), Hand = str_remove(Hand, ".*_"), Dominant = Dominant == Hand)`

Comment: @user2021713  No, it should work without any argument.  I am using `R 3.5.1` and `dplyr_0.7.6`

Comment: I can confirm that the second example works as needed. Quite elegant and flexible solution. And row_number() works indeed without argument. I think I had some packages loaded in the wrong order and that was causing unexpected behavior.

Comment: Also when we omit `id = row_number()` then we can keep original id values and find hand pairs later. Good flexible solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

With a small data frame (i.e., few variables, regardless of the number of cases), "hand-coding" may be the easiest approach:

```
with(df, data.frame(id = c(id,id), Gender=c(Gender,Gender), Age=c(Age, Age), 
                    Hand = c(rep("R", nrow(df)), rep("L", nrow(df))),
                    Present = c(Present_R, Present_L),
                    Dominant = c(Dominant=="R", Dominant=="L")
                    ))
```

Comment: This solution almost seems to work, but for me for some reason Age will be incremented by 1 and Gender will be represented by numbers 1 and 2.

Comment: Well, I can't think of any other reason than Age and Gender being factors in your data frame. You can bypass this using `as.numeric(as.character(df$Age))`  and `as.character(df$Gender)`

Comment: Yes that was the reason. Thanks!